# symfony sfDoctrineRouteCollection routing throws 404 error "Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL..."

Tags: symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4

I have the following routing configuration:

```
entry:
  class:            sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:          ProjectEntry
    module:         entry
    prefix_path:    /entry
    column:         slug
    with_show:      false
    model_methods:
      { object: getEntryBySlug }
  requirements:
    slug:             \w+
```

which, among others, gives me the following output with the symfony app:routes :

```
entry_edit             GET      /entry/:slug/edit.:sf_format
```

at lib/model/doctrine/ProjectEntryTable.class.php I have the following method:

```
public static function getEntryBySlug($parameters)
{
  return Doctrine_Core::getTable('ProjectEntry')->findOneBySlug($parameters['slug']);
}
```

However, when I enter an URL such as:

> frontend_dev.php/entry/my-slug/edit

I get the following error:

> 404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
>   Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/entry/my-slug/edit" (/).

(assume that my-slug is a valid slug for some record at ProjectEntry table)

I haven't found the cause of this error, what may I be doing wrong?

As far as I can tell, the problem is at the routing configuration (but where?!), because even if I try to debug something at my executeEdit action, I notice that I don't even get there. (If it's needed, I can post more code/output here...)

Any ideas deeply appreciated...

Comment: Hello, Javier! Did you debug `getEntryBySlug` method? Does it get there?

Comment: yes it does... I know have resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it!

I just had to remove the requirement for the slug and that was it.

The thing is that sfDoctrineRouteCollection (and maybe other sfObjectRouteCollections? anyone knows?) generates its routes, like the edit one, as:

```
prefix/column/edit
```

so if column has a \w+ requirement, it is basically saying that anything after the prefix is part of the column, including the '/edit' part. Removing the requirement loads the default one ([^ / \ \ .]+), which as far as I understand of regexes says that the next '/' is the limit...

sorry for such a newbie question, but it is now solved...